# Send and information to Asana from sql server via api asana php

Tags: php, asana, asana-connect

I need to know how i can make an app how can sent information from a sql server database to asana and return from asana to a sql server

Comment: Please provider a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

One resource you might look into is a small proof-of-concept project we made called [asana2sql](https://github.com/Asana/asana2sql). It, or something like it, might be a good starting point for you to see how our API can be made to communicate with a SQL database.

Comment: Ok, That option could give me live communication between my database and Asana?

Comment: Cause i need send and receive information about my tasks and projects